# How can I get an XML element's attribute with Perl's XML::Simple?

Tags: xml, perl

I have a Perl script that reads a XML file that doesn't have content, only attributes in the element.

Like this:

```
<league>
<game name="bla"/>
</league>
```

Now I try to get the game attribute 'name'.

I tried using `$xml->{league}->{game}->{name}` and `$xml->{league}->{game}->['name']` but they are both not working. Something about a hash problem.

Is there anybody who can help me get the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, from the XML you posted, I get this:

```
Entity: line 3: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: league line 0 and leage
```

It doesn't even appear to be a strict/warnings issue because it appears when I comment my USUW out.

But if you have the right tags, this should work:

```
$xml->{game}{name};
```

And if I call `XMLin` with `KeepRoot => 1`, you'll find it at:

```
    $xml->{league}{game}{name};
```

If you are having trouble locating how the data is being read in, do this:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

my $xml = XMLin( $input );
say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $xml ], [ '$xml' ] );
```

And then use the path to the structures presented.

---

Note:

```
$xml->{league}->{game}->['name'];
```

should have died with: "Not an ARRAY reference at" even without warnings enabled. `['string']` is a reference to an array with the string `'string'` as the sole element. And, if `$xml->{league}{game}` *were* an array, it would have died with a non-numeric error, because strings don't address arrays.

Comment: $xml->{game}{name}; gives me a:
Not a HASH reference at parser.pl line 22.

Comment: @baklap, see the suggestion for `Data::Dumper`.

Comment: thanks, made it output to a file. But I see what's wrong. The xml I posted was just a a quick example, not the real xml. My bad.   

The thing that is going wrong is that some are {element} things and some are ['name'] (don't know what the difference is) I'm able to print the {element} things, but the ['name'] things arent printable, I don't know how to do that...

Comment: @baklap, I don't understand "['name'] things." What options are you passing to XMLin? If it appeared in the dump as `['name']` then it's the same thing as: `$array_ref->[0] = 'name'`, if you see square brackets, it's in an array--although I don't understand why it wouldn't have the attribute *value* (`"blah"` in the toy case) near by it.

Answer (score 4):

I normally instantiate my XML::Simple objects like this:

```
use XML::Simple ':strict';
my $xs = XML::Simple->new( KeepRoot => 1, KeyAttr => 1, ForceArray => 1 );
```

it allows the structure to be consistent between single and possibly multiple sub-elements.  With those settings, this code gets your value:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple ':strict';

my $xs = XML::Simple->new( KeepRoot => 1, KeyAttr => 1, ForceArray => 1 );
my $ref = $xs->XMLin('data.xml');
print $ref->{league}[0]{game}[0]{name};
```

I added another game tag, and an attribute on the league tag as an example, this is the xml:

```
<league name="baz"> 
    <game name="bla"/>
    <game name="foo"/>
</league>
```

And the Data::Dumper output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'league' => [
                      {
                        'game' => [
                                  {
                                    'name' => 'bla'
                                  },
                                  {
                                    'name' => 'foo'
                                  }
                                ],
                        'name' => 'baz'
                      }
                    ]
        };
```

Comment: Setting `KeyAttr => 1` doesn't make much sense.  Perhaps you mean `KeyAttr => {}`.

Comment: KeyAttr => [], rather, I guess '1' would break on XML tags named '1'